# How to remove generated build artifacts from Maven's target directory?

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin

How to remove generated build artifacts from Maven's target directory? Maven generates a jar or war file to target directory. I'd like to remove that file after maven has installed the jar/war file to local repository (that is, after maven has executed the 'install' goal). The remove could happen either at install goal or separate goal I execute manually.

Note, that I'd like leave other parts of target directory intact, for example target/site and target/surefire-reports.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what's the reason behind this?

Comment: I've seen this done before when someone wants to create an artifact such as an NSIS exe file but are using the jar artifact type because it has a convenient set of lifecycle bindings, or if they don't care about the intermediate artifact (e.g. the jar file from which the exe is produced.)

Comment: Basically I am running the maven build inside a continuous integration server, and I am only interested in reports and stuff that gets installed to local repo. The rest of the files is just wasting space and my jar files happen to be rather large.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Just use the clean plugin and run an execution after the install phase:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>auto-clean</id>
        <phase>install</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>clean</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <filesets>
            <fileset>
              <directory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</directory>
              <includes>
                <include>**/*.jar</include>
              </includes>
            </fileset>
           </filesets>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: +1 for the filter, but the directory element should be ${project.build.outputDirectory} to allow for overridden values

Comment: I needed to delete only a particular directory from the results. Since version 2.3 the plugin deletes the entire directory by default unless you specify the excludeDefaultDirectories property within the <configuration> tag.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built into Maven that can do this. You could use the [antrun](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) plugin to execute an Ant script after install that deletes the artifact, or use the [exec](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html) plugin to use the command line to delete the artifact, or write your own plug-in.

I suggest there is little value, if any, in doing any of these things. Maven is designed to place intermediate and final artifacts in `target` to make follow-on builds more efficient. The reason that there is nothing available to do this already is an indicator that this is of little value. If it is of value to you, you have a few options.

Comment: Well, that's just not true. See domi's answer. Having that said, I still wonder why would one do this.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am a little bit late. But I guess the issue was, that a maven project archives the artifacts automatically. In my case, I disabled the automatic archiving and just archived the artifacts manually using the post build actions. This way, only the artifacts that I am interested in are archived. I am willing to leave the generated artifacts on disk until the next build runs.